# If $P$ is a prime then $R/P$ is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know the same question has been already asked here. So, I am not asking for any proof rather to find out what's wrong with my proof.

So, this is what I did: Let, $a+p, b+p \in R/P$, since $P$ is a prime, $ab + p = 0+p, ab\in R \Rightarrow (a+p)(b+p) = 0+p \Rightarrow a+p = 0+p \vee b+p = 0+p.$ Thus, $R/P$ is an integral domain.

Please could anyone tell me in details what's wrong with my proof?

Comment: I don't see you conclude that $a+P = 0+P$ or $b+P = 0+P$ from $(a+P)(b+P) = 0 + P$

Comment: Yes, I did. Please see the line before conclusion.

Comment: You should use that $P$ is a prime ideal.  I don't see you really using that $ab\in P \Rightarrow (a\in P\vee b\in P)$

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. For example: $xy = 0$ means that $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. Doesn't it? I applied the same concept here.

Comment: I mean, if you say $xy=0\Rightarrow x=0\vee y=0$ you are supposing $R/P$ doesn't have zero divisors and that is which you have to prove.
Not every ring has the property of $ab=0\Rightarrow a=0\vee b=0$, see $\mathbb{Z}_4$ for example, in which $2*2=0$.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------


Edit: I've deleted my last comment so I put what it said:
"When you say $(a+P)(b+P)=0+P$ you miss a lot of steps to arrive to $a+P=0+P$ or $b+P=0+P$.".

Comment: Sorry, I mean "I don't see how you..."  Kind of moot now though since @LeviathanTheEsper showed you the missing steps.  To respond to your comment on that answer though, the steps s/he shows are the critical steps.  Your comment leads me to believe you still don't understand the relationship between prime ideals and domains.

Comment: @Callus, I understand this now. Actually, I thought it was very obvious to see how I got $(a+p)(b+p) = 0+p$ from $ab+p = 0+p$.

Answer (score 2):

When you say $(a+P)(b+P)=0+P$ you miss a lot of steps to arrive to $a+P=0+P$ or $b+P=0+P$.

You should say something like this:
Let's suppose that
$(a+P)(b+P)=0+P$
but $(a+P)(b+P)=ab+P$, so $ab+P=0+P\Rightarrow ab\in P\Rightarrow a\in P\vee b\in P$ (Why?) $\Rightarrow a+P=0\vee b+P=0$...
And like that.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I missed all those tiny tiny little steps.